# How to make my login page vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Hello im workin on a project and i need to make this php login page vulnerable sqli .. i tried as much as i can to remove functions that escape special chars
But when i try to inject

```
' or '1' = '1'
```

nothing happen ... 
login.php :

```
 include ("config.php"); 

  $username = $_POST['username']; 
  $password = $_POST['password']; 

  $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row

  if($count == 1) {  
     session_register("username");
     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;

     header("location: welcome.php"); //set a http header
  }else {
      header("location: failed.php");
  }
```

Comment: First question: Why are you even willing to do that?

Comment: @AaronJonk Could be for learning how SQL Injection Attacks work?

Comment: `nothing happen` sounds like a fatal error. What is the status code of the page? Have you checked your error log?

Comment: @AaronJonk preparing a vulnreable lab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are injecting such SQL in the password field, your query will fail.

With `' or '1' = '1'`

your query will become :

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '' or '1' = '1''
--     Syntax error a single quote is in excess --------------------------------^
```

You can remove the last single quote of your injection : `' or '1' = '1`

Comment: But still this won't work due the to count to be one right?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman indeed, but the `LIMIT 1` and changing the `$count == 1` were already mentionned in other answers, I didn't want to *steal* others solutions

Comment: But `LIMIT 1` isn't there in the question or the OP right?

Comment: Well, he can change either the code, either the injection (he has to change the injection because of the syntax error that it will provide)

Comment: @Cid it worked without changing the code neither the injection i just forgot to remove the quote as you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

> But when i try to inject `' or '1' = '1'`

Try this

```
 $_POST['username'] = "' OR 1 LIMIT 1 --";
```

You can even use/add `OFFSET` to pick the user you want (by row).

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '' OR 1 LIMIT 1 --' and password = '$password'
```

Then (because of LIMIT 1)

```
 if($count == 1) {
```

Is True.  The `--` is the start of a inline comment in SQL, so the rest of the query is ignored. Which has obvious benefits as we can shorten or simply the query.  The fewer conditions the better and we want access to the end of the query for Limit and Offset.

This also illustrates the folly of searching for the Password.  If that was checked in code, this would not log you in.  But because it's not, it will, timing attacks and whatnot aside.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer, which is more complete than our answers

Comment: @Cid - thanks. this is probably the most common  form this attack would take.

Comment: When you use `LIMIT` clause you should also add in `ORDER BY id` clause to get deterministic results assuming the id column exists and is a primary key which it does in 9 out of the 10 cases, otherwise you could try the deprecated `ORDER BY 1` SQL standard syntax, people tend to place the primary key column first in the table.

Comment: I would just iterate though them, find any interesting accounts, and then change the password and email.  etc... :-)

Comment: i know @ArtisticPhoenix i mean `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is non deterministic so you could be missing some interesting  accounts when MySQL gives the same records because of (possible) randomness.. SQL tables and resultsets are by SQL definition **orderless** without using `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Right, but if you iterate through them all using OFFSET, I don't see how any would be missed.  Your just not guaranteed that the order this time will be the same next time.

Answer (score 1):

This *may not* work because, if you have many user records, the `$count` will be more than `1` but you are checking for only a single record to be coming out:

```php
if ($count == 1) {
```

May be try changing the condition to something like:

```php
if ($count != 0) {
```

Then the above condition will only filter out the non existent users and doesn't check for only one user to be returned.